# why C++ assignment operator need a return type?

Tags: c++

I was looking at the assignment operator of C++ class:

```
A& operator= (const A& x) {
  // do something 
  return *this;
}
```

However, why we need to return * this? Because if we call

a = b 
b is the argument of operator=, this points to a. // do something already changed the proper content of a by copying from b. How is going to get the return type? what is the recipient of this return?

Or, this is to facilitate a = b = c?

Please advise.. Thanks!

Comment: Assignment is an *expression* in C++. And returning `*this` keeps you in step with the behaviour of plain old data types.

Answer (score 6):

You don't *need* to return a reference to `this` from your assignment operator; `void` is a valid return type. However, it is a strong convention for the reason you state: it facilitates assignment chaining.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said. Having a return type in assignment operator allows for example

```
(a = b).method();
```

Though it really looks a bit strange... Of course you could just return void.

Answer (score 0):

So that it behaves the same as the  built in types

I.e

```
 A = b = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the assignment operator groups right to left, returning *this (SO A REFERENCE RATHER THAN AN OBJECT) is needed to support things like:

```
(a = b) = c
```

This can be useful in the (ugly) case that b is a function call with side effects and, more important, is consistent with the builtin =.

Note that to support

```
a = b = c
```

it is not needed for operator = to return a reference, a value would do as well, since the latter is equivalent to

```
a = (b = c)
```

Something like

```
(a=b).f()
```

would also work if operator = returns an value rather than a reference.